# Change the default value for table column with migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to change the default column value from false to true. But when I run `rake db:migrate VERSION=904984092840298` I got the following ERROR.

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "---
:from: false
:to: true
"
: ALTER TABLE "plussites" ALTER COLUMN "hide_season_selector" SET DEFAULT '---
:from: false
:to: true
'
```

Migration

```
class ChangeDefaultvalueForHideSeasonSelector < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change 
    change_column_default :plussites, :hide_season_selector, from: false, to: true 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is strange, because according to documentation ([`change_column_default`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default)) your code should work..

As an option you might define `up` and `down`:

```
class ChangeDefaultvalueForHideSeasonSelector < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column_default :plussites, :hide_season_selector, true
  end

  def down
    change_column_default :plussites, :hide_season_selector, false
  end
end
```

Comment: @Lory but it is strange, that your original code did not, because it looks correct according to documentation

Comment: It was strange also for me, because I wrote it exactly according to the documentation.

Comment: @ Andrey Deineko Yes, this project is pretty old but was involved today on it. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: @Lory so this is most likely it :)

Comment: @Lory btw, next time always add the env information to the question, like Ruby/Rails versions - it is important ;)

Comment: @Andray Deineko I will take your advice. Thank you! Спасиба :)

Answer (score 69):

You have to check which version of ActiveRecord you are using. According to your command `rake db:migrate` you are still on Ruby on Rails 4.2 or earlier.

If you are on ActiveRecord up to 4.2 ([change_column_default 4.2.9](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.9/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default)), there is no from/to option and you can define only the new default option as param.

```
class ChangeDefaultvalueForHideSeasonSelector < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change 
    change_column_default :plussites, :hide_season_selector, true 
  end
end
```

The solution above won't allow a rollback as the method don't know, what the previous default value was. This is why you have to define an separate up and down method:

```
class ChangeDefaultvalueForHideSeasonSelector < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column_default :plussites, :hide_season_selector, true
  end

  def down
    change_column_default :plussites, :hide_season_selector, false
  end
end
```

If you are on Ruby on Rails 5 or newer, there are new possibilities to define the value which was before and which one should be after by from/to ([change_column_default 5.0.0.1](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.0.0.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default)). On Ruby on Rails 5 you can use your chosen solution:

```
class ChangeDefaultvalueForHideSeasonSelector < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0] 
  def change 
    change_column_default :plussites, :hide_season_selector, from: false, to: true 
  end
end
```

I hope this explanation will help the people with comments under the other answer.